# .NET core 2.0 cookie authentication - do not redirect

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core

I am using .NET core 2.0 with cookie authentication.
My configuration looks like this:

```
services
  .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddCookie(options =>
  {
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
      options.SlidingExpiration = true;
      options.Cookie.Name = "authtoken";
  });
```

When I access unauthorized controller, I am being redirected to `/Account/Login`

In .NET Core 1.1 I was able to configure this by setting
`AutomaticChallenge = false`.
How can I configure this in .NET Core 2.0?
I just want my controller to return HTTP 403.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately the flag is well and truly removed. However you can override the "RedirectToLogin" event like so in your ConfigureServices method of your startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthenticationScheme")
    .AddCookie(options => {
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

Couple more tidbits here if you get stuck on the upgrade : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/09/16/cookie-authentication-asp-net-core-2-0/

Am I right to assume this is because it's an ajax call you are making (Or a Web API in general?). It seems like MS have gone hard with JWT being for Web API, and for Cookie to be for MVC only. Hence why the forced login page.

Comment: It's pretty dumb that MS "went hard" with that.  I'm building a SPA spp and I'm using cookies - if you add some non-SPA pages it'll just work because the cookie gets passed automatically.  JWT all needs to be done manually.  They should be continuing to support cookies for SPA.